# Azure web site load only after restart

Tags: node.js, azure, express, cleardb

Why does a web app stored in Azure cloud loads fine only for a while after restart?
My web app (node.js) is connected with clearDB.
On localhost it works perfect but only on Azure it is stuck. 
i turned on the "Always On" in the management portal, but nothing changed. the are no bugs presented in debug tools. 
I tried also from explorer and i see it shows loading... but nothing.

I am enforcing HTTPS in the web.config as explained in a azure tutorial.
I already set ssl bindings and use a custom domain,

but, in my server.js:

```
var express    = require("express");
var app        = express();
var server     = require('http').createServer(app);
var io         = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("app http ready on port "+port);
});
```

Now, i believe it is a problem with the port, but i sure let azure pick one for me as you see.

Or, maybe it's because my server.js using http while azure uses https with my ssl?

I can't change it to HTTPS in server.js and supply the cert credentials because it is already in use with my azure website (crazy)

**Just to be clear, after restart everything is fine for couple of minutes, and after that i am still able to load  the homepage. but with the first myspl query i make there is a 500 internal server error (linked to clearDB)**

Comment: i have the package.json and i push it to my git repository with 'git push azure master' while azure is the remote

Comment: you have to share more details if you want help - code, settings, etc...